# Is there a way I can simplify this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

The point here is to get a child user from the users table that is not already assigned to a particular organization. However, still include it if the child user is assigned to the *current* user.

It works, but I feel like the syntax could be simpler somehow:

```
SELECT u.userId, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.username, u2.services_user_id
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN user u2 ON u.userId = u2.services_user_id
WHERE u.enabled = 1
AND u.organization_id = 1
AND u.userId NOT IN (
    SELECT services_user_id FROM user 
    WHERE organization_id = 2 
    AND services_user_id <> 19
    AND services_user_id IS NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: FWIW I would consider this a perfectly straightforward query and in my code I might leave it as it is (though I would investigate whether I can make it more performant by eliminating the subquery, if necessary). I don't know enough to actually answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reworked my query to use NOT EXISTS and the SELECT 1 FROM user instead. Both of these are much faster and more efficient for my purposes.

```
SELECT u.userId, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.username
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN user u2 ON u.userId = u2.services_user_id
WHERE u.enabled = 1
AND u.organization_id = 14
AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM user u3 
            WHERE 
                u3.organization_id = 1
                AND u3.services_user_id <> 19
                AND u3.services_user_id IS NOT NULL 
                AND u.userId = u3.services_user_id
)
```

Same result, but cleaner and only pulling out what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could simplify your query as follows by moving your filter criteria in `on` clause

```
SELECT u.userId, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.username, u2.services_user_id
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN user u2 ON u.userId = u2.services_user_id 
                  AND (u2.organization_id <> 2 OR u2.services_user_id = 19)
WHERE u.enabled = 1
AND u.organization_id = 1
```

A sample data set would be helpful to verify the results of both queries